# Center align with table-cell

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use the table-cell way to center a div vertically and horizontally.

It works when I use the following code:

```css
div {
  display: table;
}
.logo {
  display: table-cell;
  position: absolute;
  vertical-align: middle;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

But I'd rather wrap `.logo` in another div called `.center` like here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cxvDL/), but for some reason, although it works in JSFiddle, it isn't working for me on my site.

Comment: What browser are you testing on?

Comment: Are you constrained to using the table-cell method?  Is there a reason why?

Comment: No reason, just wanted to figure out why it isn't working, testing on Google Chrome.

Comment: You are trying to center `.logo` vertically & horizontally in the parent `div`.  What controls the width and height of `div`, are these specified?

Comment: The parent element isn't relatively positioned, so .logo is being positioned relative to the next closest ancestor (if no ancestors are relatively positioned, then it is positioned relative to the document).  Don't mix vertical centering techniques, pick one or the other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to align text vertically center in div with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Here is a good starting point.

HTML:

```
<div class="containing-table">
    <div class="centre-align">
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.containing-table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px; /* for demo only */
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}
.centre-align {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px dashed gray;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.content {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top; /* Removes the extra white space below the baseline */
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/jSVyY/

`.containing-table` establishes the width and height context for `.centre-align` (the table-cell).

You can apply `text-align` and `vertical-align` to alter `.centre-align` as needed.

Note that `.content` needs to use `display: inline-block` if it is to be centered horizontally using the text-align property.

Comment: I would use list items instead of divs. Set the <li> to display: table, and then child elements will have display: table-cell. Then you can center text and do whatever you would do to a table cell.

Comment: Awesome. I was having this issue in Samsung (Android) browser. Chrome(PC) was applying `vertical-align:bottom` on table-cell but Samsung browser wasn't.. your solution did the trick.

Answer (score 30):

This would be easier to do with flexbox. Using flexbox will let you not to specify the height of your content and can adjust automatically on the height it contains.

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/mebutenura/2/edit?html,css,output)

here's the gist of the demo

```
.container{

  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

}
```

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class='content'> //you can size this anyway you want
    put anything you want here,
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: You "forgot" to demonstrate problems when content dimensions exceed parent dimensions.

Comment: The OP is looking for an answer with display: 'table-cell'.